# Saving Array to roamingSettings

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Is there a way to save `listArrays` in roaming Settings?  In js I would do it like that:

```
var test = [];  
test.push({var1:'somevalue',var2:'someotherstuff'});
```

but how to save this in:

```
var appData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
var roamingSettings = appData.roamingSettings;
```

when I try to set the variable like:

```
roamingSettings.values['myArrayList'] = test;
```

I get a typeconflict error. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [apparently](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv-LV/winappswithhtml5/thread/26a3c53a-c939-49dd-a3d5-acd20bfc7ef1) cannot store an object in the `localSettings` or `roamingSettings` values field. However, you can always just stringify and parse your array into JSON to store it instead.

```
roamingSettings.values['myArrayList'] = JSON.stringify(test);
```

and

```
test = roamingSettings.values['myArrayList'] = JSON.parse(test);
```

Just remember that the array [cannot exceed 8 KB in size for roaming settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx). Since you have to stringify it, this includes all the JSON brackets and white space!